# Configuring Quercus to talk to JavaDB

Tags: javadb, quercus

I am trying to get the Quercus PHP engine to connect with the JavaDB. I have successfully deployed Quercus in Glassfish, but I can't get Quercus to successfully connect with my database in JavaDB. Can anyone point me to an article or tutorial that treats this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives are describe here: 
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#databases

The jdbc driver should be include in the [Derby distribution](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.6.1.0.cgi#Distributions) (/lib/derbyclient.jar).